# Notify JS with element Selector Doesn't works 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, notifyjs

I'm using Notify JS from here :

http://notifyjs.com/

And this is my HTML :

```
  <div>
    <p><span class="elem-demo">aaaa</span></p>
    <script>
      $(".elem-demo").notify(
        "Hello Box",
        {
          autoHide:false
        }
      );
    </script>
  </div>
```

It doesn't work correctly. I can see the arrow, but not the message.

I've check using my browser "inspect element", the class notifyjs-container has "display:none" and when i try change it into "display:inline" via my own css, the message does appear, but without its animation.

Anybody can help ?

Here I attach the image of the small arrow i said earlier :

[image: Arrow]

Comment: Try putting the `notify` setup inside the doc ready, ie:  `$(function() { $(".elem-demo").notify("Hello"); });`

Comment: oh wow, it works, thanks, can you explain why is this happen?, and how your solutions works ?, if you okay, please write it as answer, so i can tick it. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `notify` setup inside the doc ready, ie:

```
$(function() { 
    $(".elem-demo").notify("Hello");
});
```

What is happening is that the `.notify()` script is running before the page has fully rendered, so the `.elem-demo` does not yet exist when `$(".elem-demo")` tries to find it, so the `.notify()` has nothing to attach itself to.

```
$(function() { ...
```

is shorthand for

```
$(document).ready(function() { ...
```

which is jquery's way of saying - don't run this script until the page elements have completely finished loading.

It's generally a good idea to put all your scripts into a ready function like this (multiple `$(function() { ...` can be called, they don't need to be all in the same one).

More info on the jquery learning page:  https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/